# Python 3 smtplib has no attribute SMTP when sending an email

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I'm trying to send a really simple email in Python 3 using CodeRunner to script and MacBook Terminal to run And every time I run it, tons of errors come up. I'm sending the email using yahoo mail.

Here's my code:

```
import smtplib
SERVER = "localhost"

FROM = ['me@yahoo.com', 'Password']

TO = ["me@icloud.com"] 

SUBJECT = ["Hello!"]

TEXT = ["This message was sent with Python's smtplib."]

# actual message

message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

It throws up these errors that I can't seem to fix.
It says that smtplib has no attribute SMTP.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K

Comment: what is the name of your `python` script ? is it `email.py` ?

Comment: There's a code edit queued but it appears to need one further approval.

Comment: Please add the full error Traceback.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error and the karothiya's comment solved my issue.

Make sure that the name of your script isn't `email.py` or any other string that is identical with a package the code is trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

When reporting errors it's always better to copy and paste the full traceback unless you understand what the error message is telling you. Consider the following interactive session:

```
Python 3.6.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import smtplib
>>> smtplib.SMTP
<class 'smtplib.SMTP'>
```

As you can see, the library clearly DOES have an SMTP attribute, so the real question is "what have you done to `smtplib`"? Without an error traceback we are struggling with partial information.

Bottom line: if you need people's help fixing errors it's easiest to tell them exactly what the errors are. As a newcomer to SO I understand it's difficult to get things like code formatting right, but people are generally willing to help (and, indeed, someone else has already tried to reformat your code for you).

Comment: Thankyou:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/max/Library/Containers/com.coderunnerapp.CodeRunner/Data/Library/Application Support/CodeRunner/Debuggers/pdb.crDebugger/pdb_server.py", line 38, in main
    p._runscript(p.mainpyfile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1548, in _runscript

Comment: self.run(statement)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 431, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/max/Python/email 2.py", line 24, in <module>
    server = smtplib.smtp('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465)
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'smtp'
(Pdb)